# Secuencia de tiempos verbales (del subjuntivo imperfecto y del subjuntivo pluscuamperfecto)

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Escribí cuantro oraciones para entender la secuencia de los tiempos verbales. ¿Cuáles de ellas serían las correctas?

Tal vez él **viniera** ayer *antes de que* me **fuera**, pero no lo ví.

Tal vez él **hubiera venido** ayer *antes de que* me **fuera**, pero no lo ví.

Tal vez él **viniera** ayer *después de que* **me fuera**, pero no lo ví.

Tal vez él **viniera** ayer *después de que* **me hubiera ido**, pero no lo ví.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lamento decir que ninguna de las cuatro opciones es correcta. No se trata de la gramática de los tiempos verbales, sino de la semántica: las oraciones tal como están planteadas no tienen sentido.

En la primera parte hay varias opciones. Con “tal vez” + pretérito perfecto simple del indicativo:

1. “Tal vez él vino ayer antes de que me fuera”
2. “Tal vez él vino ayer después de que me fuera”
3. “Tal vez él vino ayer después de que me fui”

... y las mismas opciones pero con pretérito perfecto compuesto del subjuntivo:

1. “Tal vez él haya venido ayer antes de que me fuera”
2. “Tal vez él haya venido ayer después de que me fuera”
3. “Tal vez él haya venido ayer después de que me fui”

El pretérito simple no funciona de la misma manera en subjuntivo que en indicativo, de ahí que sea necesario utilizar el pretérito compuesto del subjuntivo para indicar el significado buscado. El pretérito simple del subjuntivo muchas veces no indica realmente un tiempo pasado.

En cuanto a las otras diferencias: “antes de que me fuera” va en subjuntivo, pero “después de que me fui” puede ir en indicativo, seguramente porque antes de que algo ocurra siempre es hipotético, pero después de que ocurre, es un hecho cierto. Puede usarse “después de que me fuera” también, no es incorrecto; no tiene una connotación diferente.

“Tal vez hubiera...” siempre se interpretará como equivalente a “Tal vez habría...”, es decir, un hecho potencial. No funciona para expresar un hecho dudoso. En general el pluscuamperfecto se usa muy poco.

Yo mismo tengo algunas dudas sobre todo este tema. Lo recomendable para aprender estas secuencias de tiempos y modos es leer mucho. Es muy difícil estudiar todas las posibilidades de memoria.

Comment: Entendí todo, salvo sobre "tal vez + viniera". Yo ví 2 frases: "¿Tal vez no estuviera escuchando usted?" y "Puede que viniera ayer, pero no lo vi.". Por qué aquí fue usado el subjuntivo imperfecto?

Comment: También en este enlace https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tal-vez-subjuntivo-indicativo.1676742/ se puede encontrar "Tal vez saliera ayer". Y también en esta fuente https://zonaele.com/subjuntivo-algunas-consideraciones/ se dice que se usa el subjuntivo imperfecto con tal vez en caso de gran duda. ¿O no es así?

Comment: Además, siempre pensaba que pretérito perfecto compuesto del subjuntivo (haya hecho) no se puede usar con los marcadores temporales como "ayer"'. Solo se puede usar, por ejemplo, con "esta semana", "hoy", etc. o sin indicadores algunos (Quizás se haya dormido). Tal como se usan en España pretérito indefenido (hice) vs pretérito perfecto (he hecho). Y por eso en estos casos podemos usar tanto "viniera" como "vino". ¿O no es así?

Comment: Como dije, tengo dudas sobre el tema, sobre todo sobre el diferente uso de los tiempos en otros dialectos. “Tal vez saliera ayer” me suena mal a menos que sea como discurso indirecto (*reported speech*). Nunca leí que no se pueda utilizar el pret. perf. comp. del subj. con “ayer”.

Comment: Pues, yo mismo encontré muchas oraciones en Linguee donde el pret. perf. comp. del subj. se usa con "ayer". Pero, por supuesto, no encontré algo como "lo has hecho ayer". Siempre pensaba en que el pret. perf. comp. del subj. funciona de la misma manera como pretérito perfecto indicativo. Pero parece que no es así.